# Is there any other way(not sendKeys) to enter text into textbox using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Is there any other way(not sendKeys) to enter text into textbox using selenium webdriver ?

Comment: Why would there be another way? What is the problem with sendKeys? API designers rarely provide 5 methods doing the same thing.

Comment: One interviewer asked this question...

Answer (score 1):

Any other way is only to use native Javascript action to enter the value in the text box:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

executor.executeScript("document.getElementById("textbox_id").value='new value';");
```

Comment: I'm getting error like this...                                         Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: document.getElementById(...) is null
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds.Can you tell me the solution please ?

Comment: Which version of firefox and webdriver are you using?

Comment: Firefox version is 33.1 and webdriver version is 2.44.0

Answer (score 0):

@Vasntha, try mine code its tested one

```
driver.get("http://www.qajudge.com/");
WebElement cssValue= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='s']"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('s').value='Virender Testing   
sending'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement name=driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeAsyncScript("arguments[0].value='admin'",name);
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) code-only answers aren't useful for the community. Please look at [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Try below one, which I tried in Gmail and it works

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "you .exe path here");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    //Next button element
    WebElement nextBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext"));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    //code to enter value in the email textbox
    js.executeScript("document.getElementById('identifierId').value='testemail'");
    //code to click on next button
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", nextBtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use javascript executer. Here, I have written a code that uses XPath to capture the element.

```
    WebElement webelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath");
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='Techndeck';",webelement );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Enter text using javascriptexecutor**
How to use Javascriptexecutor for entering text in an element which , I want to enter text in an Textbox which does not take the input through SendKeys​. I proceeded with using Javascriptexecutor to enter the text  Example 2. Get/Retrieve text with JavascriptExecutor. In this example, we are accessing a website and trying to retrieve the text written on the login button using JavascriptExecutor

**How To Send Texts And Get Texts Using JavascriptExecutor?,**
So in such case, we use JavascriptExecutor of Selenium WebDriver library to handle Well, let's start with handling sending text data to the text area using
*If you still have any confusions please write in the comment below*.
This is another technique to send texts using JavascriptExecutor in Selenium WebDriver. Here is the sample code: ADA.

`WebElement webl = driver.findElement(By.xpath(“xpath_expression”));JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;js.executeScript(“arguments[0].value=’SynTest’;”, webl);`

1.**How to enter text using JavaScript in Selenium WebDriver**,
Following are the commands you can use to enter text using javascript. You don't need to use sendkeys always.
Syntax:
JavascriptExecutor jexe  To enter text within a textbox identified through an xpath you can use the following notation:

```
(JavascriptExecutor) driver.executeScript("document.evaluate(xpathExpresion, document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML="+ DesiredText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account");
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('email').value='Arun Singh'");
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('passwd').value='arunsingh'");
```